# How to save bitmap locally?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm trying to save my bitmap to local storage, but it doesn't work or I just can't find it.

```
                    try {
                        val fileOutputStream: FileOutputStream =
                            context!!.openFileOutput("BitMapFileSave", Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
                        viewBitMap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fileOutputStream)
                        fileOutputStream.close()
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
```

Where is directory of my savings or how to directly save it somewhere in app like

```
app/res/drawable
```

Comment: You cannot save it in your app, because your app is read-only.

When you use `openFileOutput()` this creates the file in your app's private data directory. This file is available to your app and your app only. Other apps can't see it or read it. What are you trying to do with it?

Comment: It is in -Java- getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath().

Comment: I want to save it as PNG and then use it, I need this bitmap as image to hardcode it later.

Comment: @blackapps what do you mean by this code? Where should I make it.

Comment: You should convert it to Kotlin and then log or Toast that path.

Comment: ok I've got /data/user/0/com.example.dev.qa/files
and still don't know how to find it, what do you think about it information above?

Comment: that's what I print                         val path = context!!.getFilesDir().absolutePath

Comment: got it it is on the phone